# Bokeh - Multi-Line Plot with Categorical Values

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I'm working with this dataframe:

[image]

I'm trying to use Bokeh to generate a multi-line plot with `['Joined']` as the x-value:

```
# Split columns for multi-line plot
x = df['Joined'].tolist()
y1 = df['Mean_value'].tolist()
y2 = df['Median_value'].tolist()

# Set Figure and Plot

p = figure(height=600, width=900, toolbar_location=None, x_range=x)

p.multi_line([x, y1], [x, y2], color=['#CE1141', '#06BB6'], alpha=[0.54, 0.40], line_width=3)
```

It's giving me this right now:

[image]

I can get the desired result by plotting separate lines, but it makes using the HoverTool very complicated.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting multiple lines with Bokeh and pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520951/plotting-multiple-lines-with-bokeh-and-pandas)

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi - I saw that, but it wasn't exactly what I needed. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing values to the method in the wrong way. The first parameter is `xs` and should contain all the ***x*** series, but *not* any of the ***y*** series. Howefer you are passing `[x, y1]` for `xs`, which will plot the `y1` values as the x-coordinates for the second line. You probably intend this:

```
p.multi_line([x, x], [y1, y2], ...)
```