# How to display bokeh legends with scatter plots using a dataframe?

Tags: python, scatter-plot, bokeh

I have the following plot:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

output_file("scatter.html")
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/jz/07_isolate_selection.csv')
hash = {}

c = ('aliceblue', 'antiquewhite', 'aqua', 'aquamarine', 'azure', 'beige', 'bisque', 'black', 
    'blanchedalmond', 'blue', 'blueviolet', 'brown', 'burlywood', 'cadetblue', 'chartreuse', 
    'chocolate', 'coral', 'cornflowerblue', 'cornsilk', 'crimson', 'cyan', 'darkblue', 'darkcyan', 
    'darkgoldenrod', 'darkgray', 'darkgreen', 'darkgrey', 'darkkhaki', 'darkmagenta', 'darkolivegreen', 
    'darkorange', 'darkorchid', 'darkred', 'darksalmon', 'darkseagreen', 'darkslateblue', 'darkslategray', 
    'darkslategrey', 'darkturquoise', 'darkviolet', 'deeppink', 'deepskyblue', 'dimgray', 'dimgrey', 'dodgerblue', 
    'firebrick', 'floralwhite', 'forestgreen', 'fuchsia', 'gainsboro', 'ghostwhite', 'gold', 'goldenrod', 
    'gray', 'green', 'greenyellow', 'grey', 'honeydew', 'hotpink', 'indianred', 'indigo', 'ivory', 'khaki', 
    'lavender', 'lavenderblush', 'lawngreen', 'lemonchiffon', 'lightblue', 'lightcoral', 'lightcyan', 
    'lightgoldenrodyellow', 'lightgray', 'lightgreen', 'lightgrey', 'lightpink', 'lightsalmon', 'lightseagreen', 
    'lightskyblue', 'lightslategray', 'lightslategrey', 'lightsteelblue', 'lightyellow', 'lime', 'limegreen', 
    'linen', 'magenta', 'maroon', 'mediumaquamarine', 'mediumblue', 'mediumorchid', 'mediumpurple', 'mediumseagreen', 
    'mediumslateblue', 'mediumspringgreen', 'mediumturquoise', 'mediumvioletred', 'midnightblue', 'mintcream', 'mistyrose', 
    'moccasin', 'navajowhite', 'navy', 'oldlace', 'olive', 'olivedrab', 'orange', 'orangered', 'orchid', 'palegoldenrod', 
    'palegreen', 'paleturquoise', 'palevioletred', 'papayawhip', 'peachpuff', 'peru', 'pink', 'plum', 'powderblue', 
    'purple', 'red', 'rosybrown', 'royalblue', 'saddlebrown', 'salmon', 'sandybrown', 'seagreen', 'seashell', 'sienna', 
    'silver', 'skyblue', 'slateblue', 'slategray', 'slategrey', 'snow', 'springgreen', 'steelblue', 'tan', 'teal', 
    'thistle', 'tomato', 'turquoise', 'violet', 'wheat', 'white', 'whitesmoke', 'yellow', 'yellowgreen');


#loop through and assign colors:
counter = 0
for a in df.material.unique():
    hash[a] = c[counter]
    counter += 1

# generate colors:

colors = [hash[code] for code in df.material]
df['color'] = colors


source = ColumnDataSource(df)
TOOLS="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,hover"
p = figure(title="Hoverful Scatter", tools=TOOLS)
p.circle('peak.count', 'purity.score', radius=.66, source=source,
          fill_color=colors, fill_alpha=0.6, line_color=None)

hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))[0]
hover.tooltips = [
    ("material", "@material")
]

show(p)
```

How can I display a legend which corresponds to the groups defined in df.material column? The color coding works below, where I group the circles by the df.material, but I would also like to display a legend so that you know that 'aliceblue' corresponds with 'FOO' and 'olive' corresponds with 'BAR' as an example.

Thanks!

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983039/color-points-in-scatter-plot-of-bokeh). That's a lot of unique colors, but you can look into the [CategoricalColorMapper](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/mappers.html#bokeh.models.mappers.CategoricalColorMapper).

Comment: and my favorite is darksalmon!

Answer (score 0):

I Had a similar problem with my line plot and my solution was to add the p.line() in to a for loop. Check this simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419388/bokeh-how-to-add-legend-to-figure-created-by-multi-line-method/36869353#36869353).

Also check [my notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/liova99/277ff4c49bf0db46502424bf9dc0e4c4) with a more complex example, where i make a multi line plot with this method.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

On Bokeh 0.12.3

You could try making a column 'colors' for your data frame df using a dictionary, lets say:

```
colors = {'typeA':'red', 'typeB':'blue', 'typeC':'black'}
```

where the colors.keys() are from the values on your df's typeColumn

Now you add the color column to df:

```
df['colorColumn'] = [colors[key] for key in df.typeColumn.values]
```

so you only need to access those columns from the source you just defined

```
p.circle('x', 'y', size=8, fill_color='colorColumn', legend='typeColumn', source=source)
```

Hope that helps