# Color points in scatter plot of Bokeh

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

I have the following simple `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "journey": ['ch1', 'ch2', 'ch2', 'ch1'],
        "cat": ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'],
        "kpi1": [1,2,3,4],
        "kpi2": [4,3,2,1]
    }
)
```

Which I plot as follows:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bpl
import bokeh.models as bmo
bpl.output_notebook()
source = bpl.ColumnDataSource.from_df(df)
hover = bmo.HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ("index", "@index"),
        ('journey', '@journey'),
        ("Cat", '@cat')
    ]
)
p = bpl.figure(tools=[hover])

p.scatter(
    'kpi1', 
    'kpi2', source=source)

bpl.show(p)  # open a browser
```

I am failing to color code the dots according to the `cat`. Ultimately, I want to have the first and third point in the same color, and the second and fourth in two more different colors.

How can I achieve this using Bokeh?

Answer (score 18):

Here's a way that avoids manual mapping to some extent. I recently stumbled on `bokeh.palettes` at [this github issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1645#issuecomment-75697289), as well as `CategoricalColorMapper` in [this issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5112). This approach combines them. See the full list of available palettes [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/palettes.html) and the `CategoricalColorMapper` details [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/mappers.html#bokeh.models.mappers.CategoricalColorMapper).

I had issues getting this to work directly on a `pd.DataFrame`, and also found it didn't work using your `from_df()` call. [The docs](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html#bokeh.models.sources.ColumnDataSource) show passing a `DataFrame` directly, and that worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import bokeh.plotting as bpl
import bokeh.models as bmo
from bokeh.palettes import d3
bpl.output_notebook()


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "journey": ['ch1', 'ch2', 'ch2', 'ch1'],
        "cat": ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'],
        "kpi1": [1,2,3,4],
        "kpi2": [4,3,2,1]
    }
)
source = bpl.ColumnDataSource(df)

# use whatever palette you want...
palette = d3['Category10'][len(df['cat'].unique())]
color_map = bmo.CategoricalColorMapper(factors=df['cat'].unique(),
                                   palette=palette)

# create figure and plot
p = bpl.figure()
p.scatter(x='kpi1', y='kpi2',
          color={'field': 'cat', 'transform': color_map},
          legend='cat', source=source)
bpl.show(p)
```

Comment: Is this really the simplest way to do this? That seems really convoluted, I need to add 2 lines and another dict just to do something that in R is <color = c>?

Comment: Also, this does not really allow for a legend, at least I can't figure out how to create one?

Comment: I originally came to this question for the same reason, and also having come from `R/ggplot2` I'm pretty blown away by the grossness that is the `python` plotting community. Take a look at plotly; same issue. You have to create lists for each series, which does, indeed, seem convoluted. I posted this answer because it was the simplest I could find at the time (granted, I'm pretty noob-ish with `bokeh`). If you can find a simpler way, please post another answer.

Comment: > the grossness that is the python plotting community  
  
  
This summarizes my feeling too. Also documentation. I miss `ggplot`

Comment: @mic You are in for a treat with [plotnine](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine)! This answer specifically asked about bokeh, so it's  not applicable here... but it's a fun observation that I can fit the whole plot code into a comment, using the df as is (note you have to quote variables in plotnine's `ggplot`). `from plotnine import *; ggplot(df, aes(x='kpi1', y='kpi2', color='cat')) + geom_point()`

Comment: Yeah I have been following `plotnine` for a while (I do miss ggplot so much...). Unfortunately I have been creating plots for people that want hover and zoom functionalities, and I cannot really move away from plotly or bokeh. Yours is not only a fun observation, but also one that highlights how easy, streamlined, and readable code could be when using gg.

Comment: @mic have to be python? Have you seen ggplotly, or considered just wrapping static plots in shiny/dash to get some of that functionality (not sure if hover is possible, but analogous functionality might be accomplished via sliders or buttons to toggle labels (ggrepel layer) and filtering thresholds might be possible)? Just an idea!

Comment: Yeah it has to be python and it has to run on jupyter notebooks unfortunately. As for some sort of interactivity we have been using the excellent holoviz panel (basically shiny for python, and more), but really we cannot move away from python (decently sized company and moving everyone to R is not an option). 
The select/deselect functionality can be replicated by panel/ipywidgets, but zooming and hovering make researchers' lives much easier.
I was using ggplot/ggplotly in my previous life and I never had to actually go to straight plotly. Thanks for the interest though!

Comment: @Thomas It's also pretty bad when `matplotlib` in Python also supports `color='@cat'`. Your choices are a rich plotting experience with `matplotlib`, or bland (but *interactive*) plotting experience with `bokeh`.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, here is the adapted code using **low-level** chart:

```
import pandas as pd

import bokeh.plotting as bpl
import bokeh.models as bmo
bpl.output_notebook()


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "journey": ['ch1', 'ch2', 'ch2', 'ch1'],
        "cat": ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'],
        "kpi1": [1,2,3,4],
        "kpi2": [4,3,2,1],
        "color": ['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'green']
    }
)
df

source = bpl.ColumnDataSource.from_df(df)
hover = bmo.HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ('journey', '@journey'),
        ("Cat", '@cat')
    ]
)
p = bpl.figure(tools=[hover])

p.scatter(
    'kpi1', 
    'kpi2', source=source, color='color')

bpl.show(p)
```

Note that the colors are "hard-coded" into the data.

Here is the alternative using **high-level** chart:

```
import pandas as pd

import bokeh.plotting as bpl
import bokeh.charts as bch
bpl.output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "journey": ['ch1', 'ch2', 'ch2', 'ch1'],
        "cat": ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'],
        "kpi1": [1,2,3,4],
        "kpi2": [4,3,2,1]
    }
)

tooltips=[
        ('journey', '@journey'),
        ("Cat", '@cat')
    ]
scatter = bch.Scatter(df, x='kpi1', y='kpi2',
                      color='cat',
                      legend="top_right",
                      tooltips=tooltips
                     )

bch.show(scatter)
```

Comment: `bokeh.charts` [doesn't exist](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7152) anymore. Is there an up to date way to accomplish this? I really like the idea of not having to manually specify a mapping.

Comment: Bokeh is changing rather frequently and I don't know. Probably a new question would be the best take.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I actually did stumble across a so-so way to do this and posted a new answer. I think it fits here well enough; this is a top google hit and there's precedent to update answers as things change (e.g. a `python3` answer where a `python2` answer already exists).

Comment: What is *"low level"* chart, and what is *"high level" chart?

Comment: It is describe whether Bokeh is used using its low-level constructors or high ones. I guess even the low-level example above is not the *lowest*. The lowest would be building the image using lines and dots.

Comment: It does not work in verison 3.1 s. error: ValueError: failed to validate Line(id='p4849', ...).line_color: expected either None or a value of type Color, got 'color_key_in_dataframe'

Answer (score -2):

you could use the higher level `Scatter` like [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/charts.html#scatter)

or provide a color column to the `ColumnDataSource` and reference it in your `p.scatter(..., color='color_column_label')`

Comment: That page does not exist! (sorry about that)