# bokeh.charts is gone - what library can do interactive, colored scatterplots?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, scatter-plot

One of the visualizations I find myself doing most often is the following: I have x,y Data, labeled in categories. I need to plot this in a scatterplot, automatically coloring the dots according to the label, and generating a legend. **The visualization should then be interactive** (zoomable, hovering over points shows Metadata, etc...)

This is the perfect example of what I am looking for - something that was existent in the now-deprecated [bokeh.charts library](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.0/docs/user_guide/charts.html):

[image]

I know I can do this non-interactively with seaborn:

```
fig = sns.lmplot(x="Length", y="Boot", hue="class", fit_reg=False, data=df)
```

I can plot interactively with bokeh, but only on a low level, without colors or legend:

```
p = Scatter(df, x="Length", y="Boot", plot_width=800, plot_height=600, 
    tooltips=TOOLTIPS, title="Cars")
```

I also know there exist various workarounds, manually defining color palettes, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48089485/4629950). However, this is ridiciously convoluted for something that used to be a simple oneliner (and still is, in R). The replacement, Holoview, does not seem to support coloring in scatterplots: [Source](http://holoviews.org/Reference_Manual/holoviews.element.html)

So, any recommendations for a Python package that supports this out-of-the-box in a oneliner, instead of manually writing this code on a low-level basis?

Comment: Pretty sure brokeh.charts was just moved to https://github.com/bokeh/bkcharts which in turn recommends http://holoviews.org/

Comment: @FHTMitchell: True, but holoviews does not have the functionality I need...

Comment: I don't have the time now to write out a full answer but you may be interested in plotly's python api.

Comment: I wish the old documentation would make it clear that this was deprecated... Spent time learning bokeh to learn it doesn't have this primary function anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty trivial to achieve in modern versions of Bokeh:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers as df
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

SPECIES = ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']

p = figure(tooltips="species: @species")
p.scatter("petal_length", "sepal_width", source=df, legend="species", alpha=0.5,
          size=12, color=factor_cmap('species', 'Category10_3', SPECIES))

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. I have changed the "accepted answer" mark to this question since I think it is what most people stumbling upon this question in the future will be looking for.

Comment: This looks like it requires to populate your code with all possible variations in your data (`SPECIES = ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']`) in order to color them. Sort of falls apart when you need hundreds of different colors, decided based on data at runtime.

Comment: @IanBoyd Suffice to say after ~12 years of supporting Bokeh, I can state confidently that almost no-one is in that position, with the exception of a few folks building higher level tools on top of Bokeh. If that's you, that's cool! But in that case you can (should) write the short utility function that auto-generates palettes in whatever specific way is suitable for your tool or use-case, because not everyone's needs are the same in that regard. Bokeh is a set of building blocks that can be flexibly composed, not high-level or opinionated statistical charting tool.

Answer (score 4):

The [HoloViews](https://holoviews.org) library is a good replacement for the bokeh charts API. However since the API is quite unfamiliar to people who are used to imperative plotting APIs we have recently released a new library called [hvPlot](https://hvplot.pyviz.org), which tries to mirror the pandas plotting API quite closely while providing the interactivity afforded by bokeh as well as some of the more advanced features of HoloViews (e.g. automatic faceting, widgets and datashader integration). To recreate the plot from above you would do something like this:

```
import bokeh.sampledata.autompg as mpg
import hvplot.pandas  # adds hvplot method to pandas objects

myPlot = mpg.autompg.hvplot.scatter(
        x='displ', y='hp', by='cyl',
        fields={'hp': 'Horsepower', 'displ': 'Displacement'},
        title='HP vs. DISPL (shaded by CYL)'
)
hvplot.show(myPlot) # view the plot in a browser (hvplot doesn't support modal dialogs)
```

[image]

Note that you will be able to replace the `fields` argument with more explicit `xlabel` and `ylabel` arguments in the next release.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was looking for! However, it does not seem to work with Spyder: I get `Out[142]: 
:NdOverlay   [cyl]
   :Scatter   [Displacement]   (Horsepower)` instead of an image... (Windows / Python 3.6)

Comment: Yes, it's primarily set up to work in the notebook. But you should be able to display the returned object with:

hvplot.show(obj)

Comment: This did not work unfortunately, but I didn't have time to further investigate and since this looks like a worthy alternative, I will accept it for now.