# plot legend in multi_index figure plot

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am working to plot a mulit_index data for below table, which each line in the figure is related to data in columns{10,11,12,21,26,27}

[my data as "temp"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESYno.png)

after I am plotting a multi_index figure :

[multi_index figure plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzQyi.png)

I want to add the legend to my plot as well but as "temp" is multi_index pandas.DataFrame, I could access to values {10,11,12,21,26,27}, which will change in each query.

below is my code, please help me to what should I put in **legend** ?

```
p=figure(x_axis_type="datetime")
table=pivot_table(data,index=['SDATE','SUBRACK_NO'],columns=['SLOT_NO'],values='ID_73393960',aggfunc={'mean'})
temp=table.query('SUBRACK_NO=="2"')
temp=temp.dropna(axis=1,how='all')   # to remove all nan values from data
temp.reset_index(level=1, drop=True, inplace=True)   # to drop index Subrack_no as it make problem for plotting
numlines=len(temp.columns)
mypalette=Spectral11[0:numlines]

p.multi_line(xs=[temp.index.values]*numlines,
             ys=[temp[name].values for name in temp],
             line_color=mypalette,
             line_width=2,legend="**temp.columns.levels[1]**")

show(p)   #show(gridplot([[p, p_filtered]]))
```

My "temp" data is as follw :

```
    mean
SLOT_NO 10  11  12  21  26  27
SDATE                       
2018-04-12 01:00:00 30.178571   30.214286   29.107143   28.571429   28.714286   29.250000
2018-04-12 02:00:00 23.500000   24.250000   22.928571   25.214286   23.642857   22.785714
2018-04-12 03:00:00 18.642857   19.107143   18.678571   17.535714   17.857143   17.785714
2018-04-12 04:00:00 13.071429   13.178571   14.500000   13.214286   14.000000   14.142857
2018-04-12 05:00:00 12.321429   11.928571   13.464286   12.535714   12.785714   13.678571
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bokeh how to add legend to figure created by multi\_line method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419388/bokeh-how-to-add-legend-to-figure-created-by-multi-line-method)

Comment: @NiklasMertsch actually this is not the answer. my problem is that my data is multi_index, it is not easy like that. how to access to temp columns values ?

Comment: Can you provide sample data to copy and test? What text do you want to show up in the legend given that data?

Comment: @NiklasMertsch, I want to add  {10,11,12,21,26,27} for legend, if you take a look at (my data as "temp") photo above. Thanks

Comment: @Sadegh please add your data as `text`, a picture of it doesn't help.

Comment: @IanThompson Actually I am new in Stackoverflow and I don't know how to attach text file. when I am pasting to area, it will show as scrambeled which is not useful. please help me

Comment: @Sadegh Paste it, then highlight what you pasted and convert it to code format like you did with the code you already posted.

Comment: @IanThompson, Thanks, I have added data :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're pretty close to what you want.  Using your the data you already have, it looks like you have hierarchical columns with `mean` being the upper level. Assuming your dataframe is `df`:

```
df.mean.plot()
```

Should return this:

[image: plot]

Is that what you're trying to get?

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that when I am using "multi_line" in python, I cannot add multiple legends.One way which is suggested is to use "for" loop but using "multiline" is faster way .

Comment: @Sadegh do you need to use `multi_line`? What is it that you want from `multi_line` that isn't produced from this plot?

Comment: ,from multiline, I want to have multi legend as well.

Comment: @Sadegh can you provide an example image of what you mean? The plot I provided has a legend with all columns listed.